# gpg: ify: skipped: public key not found when I made the encryption myself

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, terminal, gnupg

I am trying right now to set up my own encryption with private and public key. I am following this tutorial:

http://wooledge.org/~greg/crypto/node41.html

when I try to use

> gpg -verify message.asc,

it says the

> gpg: ify: skipped: public key not found gpg: message.asc: encryption
>
> failed: public key not found

When I look at my public keys it says

> MYNAME@ubuntu:~/.gnupg$ gpg --list-keys
>   /home/MYNAME/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
>   ---------------------------------------- pub   2048R/FF713BDB 2016-02-04 uid                  MY NAME
>    sub   2048R/9168A1D6 2016-02-04

I tried to import my public key and I get nothing. I am sure it is a basic problem, but I have no idea of what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the answer, the tutorial says

> -verify message.asc

where it should be

> --verify message.asc